# How to create SQL index for a faster join?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, android-sqlite

I have the following query **without where clause** for getting a list of all Employees and their Orders:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, OrderID, OrderDate
FROM Employees inner JOIN Orders 
 ON Employees.ID = Order.EmployeeID
```

I can define two indexes: **1)** on column `Employees.ID` and **2)** on column `Order.EmployeeID`. If I want to have only one index, which one should I define for a faster join?

I am using SQLite for Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query leaves out a lot of details, such as the sizes of the tables and the structure.  However, based on the names of the entities, I can speculate on some of the details.

First, in SQLite, every table is given a primary key.  You should take advantage of this by defining a primary key on each table.

Assuming that `Employees.ID` is a candidate for a primary key on `Employees` (that is, the values are unique), it should be defined as the primar key.  This acts just like an index.

With this structure, the engine should process the query by reading the `Orders` table and looking up the value in the `Employees` table.  Assuming that the `Orders` table is larger than `Employees`, I think this would be the most efficient method for satisfying the query.

In other words, just make sure that `Employees.ID` is the primary key.

EDIT:

You need to read both tables.  There are basically three options.  You can sort both tables and then merge them.  This is expensive because sorting is expensive.

You can read either table sequentially and look up the values in the other.  Sequentially reading a table is faster than doing random reads (via an index lookup).  It is faster to do the sequential the read on the larger table, presumably `orders` with the index lookups on the smaller table, presumably `employees`.

If the `orders` table is very wide (lots of columns), then an index on `orders(id, orderdate)` could perhaps be an improvement.  This is a "covering" index and so would not require accessing the original data.

Comment: Is not it better to add another index `Order.EmployeeID` in addition to primary key `Employees.ID`?

Comment: @breceivemail . . . Assuming that `id` is an integer field, the nyou have an integer primary key and the declaration automatically creates the index.

Comment: I understood. Now my question is about to add another index on `foreign key`. Is it a good idea to add another index on **foreign key** `Order.EmployeeID`?

Comment: @breceivemail . . . Probably not.  You want to do the full table scan as cheaply as possible.  And that is as a full table scan rather than by using a random reads, as an index would typically do.